# How is code managed before OOP?

Tags: design-patterns, procedural-programming

The most common issue for non-OOP is:

how to prevent conflict of function name when the project becomes extremely huge?

For OOP we can simply put the functions into different classes,but what's the approach for procedure programming?

Comment: They just used many slightly different crappy names...

Comment: Without namespaces, I think it's the only practice. :)

Comment: There's no specific question in here. It depends on the language and circumstances. We had all kinds of techniques back in the day.

Comment: @Pekka do you know when is `namespace` created?

Comment: @user198729 Depends on what language. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace

Comment: Oh,I'm mainly interested in c

Answer (score 4):

In C++, without using OOP, you would use namespaces.

In C, people tend to create functions with prefixes (e.g. "sqlite3_some_function_name") and/or marking non-public functions `static`.

Anyway, when using long and descriptive names for functions, no two functions will have the same name *OR* if they do, they're identical and one of them can be removed.

Comment: By marking non-public functions static,it's only visible within the very file,right?

Comment: Did `c` support `namespace` by the time windows os comes out?

Comment: The Windows API defines functions in C, not C++. Only C++ supports namespaces, C still doesn't. That's why I said that in C you'd usually use prefixed function names.

Comment: So for c projects,the only approach is "prefixed function names"?

Comment: Yes, it's the only bulletproof solution IMO.

Answer (score 1):

[Namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace_%28computer_science%29) are widely used.